# Select from two tables where rows from second table should be shown as columns in first

Tags: php, sql, join

I have two tables in MySQL:

Table **entry**:

```
id | name         | date
1  | Test Entry   | 12/12/2013
2  | Test Entry 2 | 12/12/2013
```

Table **note**

```
id | entry_id | name  | value 
1  | 1        | note1 | value1
2  | 1        | note2 | value2
3  | 2        | note1 | value1
4  | 3        | note4 | value4
```

Where `entry_id` in `note` is a foreign key to `id` in `entry`.

Is there any solution I can create with a `SELECT` that will give me a result like the following?

```
entry_id | name         | note1   | note2  | note3 
1        | Test Entry   | value1  | value2 |   -
2        | Test Entry 2 | value 1 |    -   | value3
```

I want to avoid `LEFT JOIN` here (current implementation is working like this) and want to join `note` only once if that is possible. `LEFT JOIN` is not good here, because I do not know how many notes can be attached to one entry. My current implementation works that way that I first fetch all distinct notes by name that can be found in `note`, and then build a SELECT with foreach through PHP. Finally, the `SELECT` statement looks like this:

```sql
SELECT 
E.id as entry_id,
E.name as name,
N1.value as note1_value,
N2.value as note2_value,
N3.value as note3_value
FROM entry E
JOIN LEFT note N1 ON E.id = N1.entry_id AND N1.name = 'note1'
JOIN LEFT note N2 ON E.id = N2.entry_id AND N2.name = 'note2'
JOIN LEFT note N3 ON E.id = N3.entry_id AND N3.name = 'note3'
```

Things get tricky when I join on `note` 20-30 times.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Working on that right now.

Comment: JS fiddle url: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b7ae/1

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a way to do that without joins.

I would recommend doing 2 queries.

1. select * from entry where id = `id`
2. select * from note where entry_id = `id`

and then join the results in your application code. You're right, the left joins are going to be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to use a table with one note value and a note type (number) per each line.

id  | value  | note_no

Like this you can use as much notes as you like.

You can get the notes on one line using `group_concat`.

For an example, see here: http://lietoservetruth.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/mysql-group_concat-vertival-concat-concat-records/

This is faster than asking DB twice, and it's better DB design...

Comment: Thing is, I need those note names to be columns, that you can turn on and turn off those you want or not to see.

Comment: Yes, I know about group_concat, but I was think is there maybe a way to have them in separate columns. group_concat will return me all column values as one string.